# Keras: does save_model really save all optimizer weights?

Tags: keras

Suppose you have a  Keras model with an optimizer like Adam that you save via `save_model`.
If you load the model again with `load_model`, does it really load ALL optimizer parameters + weights?

---

Based on the code of `save_model`([Link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py#L118)), Keras saves the config of the optimizer:

```
f.attrs['training_config'] = json.dumps({
                             'optimizer_config': {
                             'class_name': model.optimizer.__class__.__name__,
                             'config': model.optimizer.get_config()},
```

which, in the case of Adam for example ([Link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L447)), is as follows:

```
def get_config(self):
    config = {'lr': float(K.get_value(self.lr)),
              'beta_1': float(K.get_value(self.beta_1)),
              'beta_2': float(K.get_value(self.beta_2)),
              'decay': float(K.get_value(self.decay)),
              'epsilon': self.epsilon}
```

As such, this only saves the fundamental parameters but no per-variable optimizer weights.

However, after dumping the `config` in `save_model`, it looks like some optimizer weights are saved as well ([Link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py#L143)). Unfortunately, I can't really understand if every weight of the optimizer saved.

---

So if you want to continue training the model in a new session with `load_model`, is the state of the optimizer really 100% the same as in the last training session? E.g. in the case of SGD with momentum, does it save all per-variable momentums?

Or in general, does it make a difference in training if you stop and resume training with `save/load_model`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem your links don't point to the same lines anymore than they originally pointed to at the time of your question, so I don't know which lines you are referring to.

But the answer is yes, the entire state of the optimizer is saved along with the model.  You can see this happening in [save_model()](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a637960fab61b66848a36e6a5caf0204c155af01/keras/engine/saving.py#L149).  Also if you wish not to save the optimizer weights, you can do so by calling `save_model(include_optimizer=False)`.

If you inspect the resulting *.h5 file, for example by means of `h5dump | less`, you can see those weights.  (h5dump is part of [h5utils](https://github.com/stevengj/h5utils).)

Therefore saving a model and loading it again later should make no difference in many common cases.  However there are exceptions not related to the optimizer.  One that comes to my mind right now is an `LSTM(stateful=True)` layer which I believe does not save the internal LSTM states when calling `save_model()`.  There are possibly many more reasons why interrupting the training with save/load might not produce the exact same results as training without interruption.  But investigating this maybe makes sense only in the context of concrete code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've also found out that most of the state is saved, but as you noted with the LSTM some things are not saved. I've also noticed this now with some models (though I don't know yet what's the cause), since my _test_ performance is significantly different if I a) train a model and test it or b) train a model, save it, load it and test it. I'm using the stateful option for the batchnorm layers, so this may be related (with trainable=false).

Comment: @Jlh, is that mean the model.save() and models.save_model() do the same thing.

Comment: @Zaher88abd Yes they do the same thing.